# Intuitive Explanation to a random variable concept

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers, stationary-processes

This is from the Wikipedia page on [Stationary Processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process):

> Let Y be any scalar random variable, and define a time-series { Xt }, by Xt = Y for all t.
>
> Then { Xt } is a stationary time series, for which realisations consist of a series of constant values, with a different constant value for each realisation. A law of large numbers does not apply on this case, as the limiting value of an average from a single realisation takes the random value determined by Y, rather than taking the expected value of Y."

I cannot understand the reason for the law of large numbers not being applicable. Any explanation would help.

Just for reference,
in probability theory, the law of large numbers (LLN) is a theorem that describes the result of performing the same experiment a large number of times. According to the law, the average of the results obtained from a large number of trials should be close to the expected value, and will tend to become closer as more trials are performed.

Comment: The LLN does not hold because, here, $\frac1n\sum\limits_{t=1}^nX_t\to Y$ when $n\to\infty$ and not $\frac1n\sum\limits_{t=1}^nX_t\to E(X_1)$ (unless $Y$ is almost surely constant). Note that $E(X_1)=E(Y)$.

Comment: I see But, why does the first condition you mentioned hold? Please excuse my ignorance, as I'm new to learning these concepts.

Comment: "why does the first condition you mentioned hold? " Well, because $X_t=Y$ for every $t$ hence $\frac1n\sum\limits_{t=1}^nX_t=Y$ for every $n$, with full probability.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't that be the case for every random variable? Why does the law of large numbers hold at all then?

Comment: What I mean to ask is that how this case if different from the cases where the law of large numbers do hold?

Comment: That is to say, consider X is a random variable denoting the outcome of a die roll. The law of large numbers holds here, right? So, basically, here, the time series value at every instant is equal to the value of the random variable denoting the outcome of the die roll. So, why won't the average of Xt values equal 3.5 when the number of trials tends to infinity?

Comment: This is a special case.  The values are something like $X_t=2$ for every $t$.  The only thing that's random is the constant value of the time series.  We roll the die once, and it come up $2$ and that determines the entire series.  When we roll the die again, we get a different series.

Comment: So, this means to say that I roll a dice once, observe the outcome and set the time series value to that observed value for all t. That is, the dice is not rolled ever again after the first roll, and he value obtained on the first roll is used to decide the value of the time series at every instant. Is this what is implied?

Comment: "how this case if different from the cases where the law of large numbers do hold" The setting of the LLN is when one **repeats** the experiment. In @saulspatz's example, one throws the die once. For the LLN to be relevant, one should throw the die again and again, and record the sequence of results.

Comment: Yes exactly.  Read the first sentence of the discussion you quoted once more, with this in mind.

Comment: Right. So, here the die is thrown only once, right? And by a single realization of the time series, they mean that for that time series, the value of Y is fixed. Now, if I want another realization, I roll the die again and fix the value of Y. Right?

Comment: You've got it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you. That helped largely.

Comment: In this regard, could you help me out with one more doubt?
Suppose, Xt = cos(t+Y), where Y is uniformly distributed in [0,2pi].
Now, how do I conclude that Xt is stationary?